# Where clause when field contains comma separated values returns wrong results

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've a table that contains an id column and value column that contain comma separated values, So i want to get rows when the value column is equal to the id column,

**Table structure is :**

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `value`) VALUES
                   (NULL, '1,2,3,4,5'),
                   (NULL, '1,2,3,4,5');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE id = value
```

The query supposed to not return any results since no matching, but below is the returned results :

[image]

Server version: 5.5.52-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Is there anything i'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Saving data as csv is very bad database design.you should normalize your db. In the meantime you can learn about `find_in_set`

Comment: I'm not trying to find if the id exists in the value column or not, i want to check if value contains only one id and it's the id in the same row

Comment: `value`is a keyword in mysql

Comment: that is the case, query must return 0 results

Comment: the query not throwing errors on value keyword and i used another name  and  returns the same results.

Comment: I gues there is some automatic conversation from varchar to int

Comment: If you tried SELECT * FROM \`test\` WHERE cast(\`id\` as CHARACTER) = \`value\` you get what your expecting

Comment: `id` is not equal `value` since `1` is not equal to `1,2,3,4,5`.